# Response in .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm writing a .d.ts file for libnpmpublish [(here on npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libnpmpublish#publish). One of the functions return a promise that resolves to a Response. However, throwing Response straight into the typedef file results in this error:

> Cannot find name 'Response'. ts(2304)

I've no idea what to do from here. Is there a package I need to get for this?

Playground link: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQIagHQBNnngM2gGwKYBQhwAVKYaKaAMr4B2q8U%20oADggMYDWCA5qwBO%20NsNgNw%20VKABGATwiRWAWwT1oWfLHCJGEBIIAiCcEnAB7Ra07n6OPgFdh04XzjhBc5JWoABDoIIyqCq6praVuwG4tIcPPz4yABWsLagWOaCkXG8ArL40PR87A4yuHBK0gAUAO4wnJCgnGqIuKn5kaEaWjpsDrgE0liC5sFIOQ7KEgA0iKBuOsJs5rOmgjIIA7P44JzIAJQ%20oP4GQfrrm7jGpnMAQg5YmlnmWJFrGwP5hcV9ZRVS3ioxwCZ3MbHA0Fs8CqYIhtk2%20zm5hkSXwnB0NnopkK30isMh9FgR18wnATkJcwACiNlHBWFATKAxOZcAA3LQQSxIABKWmWhKIVGAhHwAA9loIdFgHPR0QSSn9YJAql1wuAAFygZGo9GrAwfK4mBCa%206PfCCWb4qEAfk1VsJ%20011NGdIAPLzYPzxAA%20ADcxDFEp0hUkgiwXFY9vgAG8AL5AA) (Buffer is covered with @types/node)

Comment: You probably need to add a reference or import the type. I recommend you [edit] and provide an [mre].

Comment: I'll add a link to a typescript playground

Comment: Yeah, that will help! It's still good to provide some of your own code here in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that I could import @types/node-fetch and use its Response class.

Answer (score 0):

If You are talking about `ServerResponse` from `http` then You should `import` it manually as it is not builtin into the language.
Like this:

```
import { ServerResponse } from 'http'

export function publish(manifest: Object, tarballData: Buffer, options?: Options
): Promise<Response>
export interface Options {}
```